# location.reload() function is not working propely in javascript

Tags: javascript, java, jsp

Here the problem is arriving when i am using `location.reload()` in `IE` and this error is occurring

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: It's not an error. It's a safety precaution to protect users.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get

Answer (score 1):

This message is to warn you against any financial or otherwise important transaction that was completed earlier and may get initiated again as a result of running `location.reload()`